# Why can't I swap a TL071 with a 741?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, jfet

I constructed [this circuit](https://makezine.com/2014/01/08/projects-with-ryan-slaugh-simple-amplifier/) as shown for use as a simple headphone amplifier. I was so happy with myself that I made a second one for stereo, as well as using a 3915 to make a very simple volume visualizer.

The circuit uses a [uA/LM741](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm741.pdf) as a "preamp" for the 386 audio amplifier. Through my reading, I learned there are much better op-amps to use for audio applications than a 741, such as the [TL071](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl071a.pdf). So, imagine my gaiety when I discovered a set of TL071s in my parts box. Well, I'll just plug them in (swapping the TL071 in where the 741 is without changing the circuit otherwise) and...

No dice. I have to change the bias on pin 3 (the noninverting input) so that it's biased at Vcc/2, which ends up limiting the amount of "volume" I can get out as well.

My question is, why can the 741 have its NI input hooked to ground and still function fine, but the TL071 needs a "typical" mid-supply bias?

I know that the 741 is a BJT-based design and the TL071 is a JFET op-amp, and you'll have to excuse me but I'm still just learning about FETs at the moment. Is this because of the larger offset voltage in the TL071 because it's harder to match device parameters in a FET?

Comment: You seem to be coming to a mistaken conclusion most likely based on unrelated differences in circuits.  Most op-amps require the inputs to be between V+ and V- with some further narrowing the allowable input range.  Likely your 741 circuit is dual supply (V- below ground) while your TL071 circuit is single supply (V- = ground).

Comment: Hi there and thanks for your prompt response! Pardon my confusion - there is no difference between the circuits besides that I merely swapped one chip with another, and V- is at ground (I am operating single supply). Or do you mean that the TL071 is intended for single supply use?

Comment: Both of those parts suck almost equally for single supply use.

Comment: With either op-amp, you need to bias the input to be between the supplies, so if you are running single-supply, negative inputs are unusuable, and A/C coupled inputs need to be biased to a virtual ground.

Comment: If you cannot swap op-amps in a simple audio circuit, it must contain a spectacular design flaw. Without a schematic, and one which accurately reflects what was actually built, it is difficult to comment on.

Comment: Audio tinkerers regularly swap op-amps in consumer equipment, including bipolars for bi-FETs and vice versa without problems. A guitar pre-amp I used used to have a LF347 JFET-input quad op-amp in the EQ section, which is now a MC33079 with BJT input stages which works great. This is because the op-amps are in a solid circuit: properly powered, biased, decoupled, bypassed, etc. And there is enough power supply margin to play with higher-current-draw op-amps.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who responded - it's sad when even a newbie like me can understand the flaws in a circuit designed and published by someone with "15 years of design experience"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if that circuit does in some way function it's well outside of the normal operation of a [741](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Fairchild%20PDFs/LM741.pdf). The common mode range of a 741 only goes to within a couple volts of the negative rail, below that the current sinks that bias the differential front end will no longer function.

[image]

Even with a single-supply op-amp the circuit will not function properly because the op-amp output cannot swing below ground.

[image]

A horrible, horrible circuit and he did not demonstrate it working, just producing a horrid buzzing noise.

Comment: I agree, but @MJXS had it working!  ("Riddle me that Batman")

Comment: @GeorgeHerold Ah, inquisitive, aren't we? The output can't swing to the negative rail either- so it ends up being a kind of class A amplifier biased by the output not-quite-railing (at around a volt). That's my theory. The bias current may give it a bit of offset that allows it to produce both halves of the waveform to some degree, if the input voltage is small and the pot is turned towards the high gain end.

Comment: I agree that there is no way on God's green earth that this thing ought to work. The video shows an electret microphone producing some sort of response with no excitation, too. Well, Johnathan Swift had it right when he referred to "the innate perversity of inanimate objects."

Comment: I can confirm it does indeed work (to some limited degree - the gain settings are very specific on the 386 possibly as a result). Now, in light of this conversation, I understand why it shouldn't.

Comment: B..bbbbut I thought any circuit produced by a Maker (TM) is ipso facto perfect!?

Answer (score 2):

Weird,  I don't know how that first circuit worked with a 741.
Maybe there was enough current leaking out of the inverting input to bias the the input coupling cap to some value that let it run.  Biasing the non-inverting input to mid supply was the right thing to do.  To get rid of the clipping (low volume) maybe you could reduce the gain of the first stage and let the LM368 do more. (?)